# prestashop: MySQL Query For product features

Tags: mysql, product, concatenation, prestashop-1.5, multiple-value

i need to get product features in prestashop 1.5, but the probleme is that i use a modification tat enable me to put multiple value to one feature per product

example:

compatible memory cards:
 - Carte Mémoire xD
 - Memory Stick
 - Memory Stick PRO
 - MultimediaCard (MMC)
 - Carte Secure Digital (SD)

I got this query:

```
Select fl.name, fvl.value, f.id_feature
From ps_feature_lang fl Left Join
  ps_feature_product fp On fl.id_feature = fp.id_feature And fp.id_product = 291
  Left Join
  ps_feature_value_lang fvl On fp.id_feature_value = fvl.id_feature_value And
    fvl.id_lang = 5 Left Join
  ps_feature f On f.id_feature = fl.id_feature
Where fl.id_feature In (Select ps__fc_categories_features.feature_id
  From ps__fc_categories_features)
Group By fl.name, fvl.value, f.id_feature, fl.id_feature
Order By f.position
```

but if there is a feature with more than one value for a given product, it will give multiple raws for that feature
The best is a query that will concat the values for each feature that have pultiple value

thanx in advence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a small adjustment to your query.  Try this:

```
Select fl.name, group_concat(fvl.value) as values, f.id_feature
From ps_feature_lang fl Left Join
     ps_feature_product fp
     On fl.id_feature = fp.id_feature And fp.id_product = 291 Left Join
     ps_feature_value_lang fvl
     On fp.id_feature_value = fvl.id_feature_value And fvl.id_lang = 5 Left Join
     ps_feature f
     On f.id_feature = fl.id_feature
Where fl.id_feature In (Select ps__fc_categories_features.feature_id
                        From ps__fc_categories_features
                       )
Group By fl.name, fl.id_feature
Order By f.position;
```

This query removes the `fvl.value` from the `group by` and adds `group_concat()` the `select`.  I also removed the `f.id_feature`.  It seems redundant based on the `join` conditions.

Comment: I came in the meantime to the same solution with some research, making a little near the same modification ("group_concat").
Nevertheless, thank you very much for your help and I hope it's going to help a few that I know they are many to have is kind of problems.